# Message sent but doesnt receive by email address in PHPMailer?

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

Im using PHPmailer 5.4.2 and try one of its given example. It gives me true result which is "Message Sent" but the email address I have states in the code doesnt receive anything. Here is the code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>PHPMailer - Mail() basic test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php

require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = "fhgdshfgjsd";

$mail->SetFrom('verbz95@gmail.com', 'Verbo Angelo Ludovice');

$mail->AddReplyTo("verbz95@gmail.com","Verbo Angelo Ludovice");

$address = "espadadave@yahoo.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not using 5.4.2 because there is no such version. I can tell that you are using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an old example. Please [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and start with [a more recent example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mail.phps). Because you are sending using the PHP mail() function, any sending problems (and successes) will appear in your local mail server log - probably `/var/log/mail.log`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are trying to send email from your server via gmail without any authentification, therefore yahoo treats it as a forged/spam email. You will need to either:
- don't use **@gmail.com as a from address
- or forward your mail thru gmail smtp server (you will need to provide credentials), you can find all settings in your gmail\settings\pop3, imap tab